# No se muestra los archivos estáticos de Django 3.2.13 usando MEDIA_ROOT/URL

Tags: python, django, archivo, static, 404

Tengo la carpeta media/ en la raíz de proyecto, y tiene archivo (.pdf y image/*)

En settings tengo estas 2 variables

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

BASE_DIR esta como:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

También tengo esta:

```
CORE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#no se para que es, pero la pongo
```

Y en urls del proyecto (no las de la carpeta **core**) tengo:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [

................................

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Como path principal estoy usando:
***http://127.0.0.1:8000/proyecto***

En el archivo HTMl aparece el href como:

```
{{request.PATHPROJECT}}/{{ request.files.foto }}
#ruta principal          ruta de archivo
```

Y al abrir un archivo la url cambia a:

---

http://127.0.0.1:8000/proyecto/media/files/15a70b4f-ed55-4a87-a3ae-cdb727ecb01c.png

---

Pero me sale un error 404, como lo corrijo?, sin tener que cambiar el path principal.

Nota: Estoy usando una plantilla, por eso hay cosas que no conozco muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Te paso la configuracion que yo uso y no me genera problemas.

Eso si mira la version de Django que estas utilizando esto sirve solo para Django >= 1.7

settings.py

```
from unipath import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Lo pudes probar con una ruta similar:  <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}test.png"/> añade dentro de media esto, eso si fijate donde creas la carpeta.